# unsupported instruction 'mov' in inline asm moving control register to uint32_t

Tags: c, gcc, x86, inline-assembly, cpu-registers

I am using an assembly code in a C function. But gcc gives `unsupported instruction 'mov'` error for the following code:

```
uint32_t faulting_address;
asm volatile("mov %%cr2, %0" : "=r" (faulting_address));
```

I don't understand what is wrong with this.

Comment: [GCC's inline assembly](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#s3) uses AT&T syntax.

Comment: Thank you, I tried `asm volatile("movl $0, %%cr2" : "=r" (faulting_address))` but nothing changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is correct, but the error is more than likely because you're compiling for a 64-bit target, in which case the `mov` needs to be 64 bits. Just change `faulting_address` to a `uint64_t` and it will compile.

Alternatively, if you *want* it to be 32 bits, you'll need to use `-m32` or other similar option to compile for a 32-bit target.

Comment: -m32 worked for me thanks. For linking those files should I use -melf_i386?

Comment: `uintptr_t` would pick the right width depending on mode.  (Except for the x32 ABI; 32-bit pointers in 64-bit mode.  But you wouldn't normally use that for an x86-64 kernel, and CRs aren't readable in user-space.)